# Trouble passing props from functional to functional component

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am passing props to a functional component, but I keep getting an error:

```
const renderItem = ({ item }) => (

    <CommentCellClass
      key={item.key}
      commentLikes={item.commentLikes}
      .... more props
```

I try and access them in the CommentCellClass component:

```
const CommentCellClass = ({ props, navigation }) => {
  const { key, commentLikes } = props;
```

But I get the following error:

```
   TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'props.key')]
```

What am I doing wrong? The props are not null (I checked before I passed them to commentCellClass)

Sorry for the confusing name (CommentCell**Class** is a functional component). We are in the process of converting the class components to functional components in our app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where does navigation come from? I would expect your code to look like this:

```
const CommentCellClass = (props) => {
  const { key, commentLikes } = props;
  ...
}
```

or

```
const CommentCellClass = ({ key, commentLikes }) => { ... }
```